# Android: Phone isn't recognized by ADT after upgrading

Tags: android, macos, adb, adt, device

I just upgraded to the latest Android SDK (r16) and Eclipse (3.7.2). Now I can not use USB devices. I can connect the phone to my Mac (Lion) and share data but the "adb devices" returns an empty list (only emulators are displayed).

Yes.. I have "Unknown sources" and "USB debugging" turned on. I have 3 Android devices and none of them work (but they did before upgrade).

Does anyone has a fix?

UPDATE:
Can someone please test this?

Comment: try adb kill-server to force a restart.

Comment: @yorkw Do you have the latest configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Just check whether the below options are checked:

1. settings->Applications->Unknown Sources
2. settings->Applications->Development->USB debugging

I am sure but these two may be restored as default.

Comment: Nope... as I wrote I have these things on.

Comment: then "adb kill-server" may be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try adb plugin? Use "adb kill-server" and "adb start-server" and check devices. I have got same problem and it works.

Comment: Nope... Do you have the latest configuration?

Answer (score 1):

first make sure the device development usb debugging open,

and then you can using:

`adb kill-server`

`adb devices`

to refresh devices list

Comment: These are answers I've read on the other sites but no... it does not fix my problem. Do you have the latest configuration?

Comment: try this: when usb connected, you close usb debugging and reopen again, and then invoke above shell command.

Comment: Nope... would you be so kind and test this on the latest configuration?